# How to pass a SAFEARRAY from C# to COM?

Tags: c#, com

I have an ATL COM Server, where the method for the interface is

```
CVivsBasic::UpdateSwitchPlan(BSTR plan_name, SAFEARRAY* plan)
```

And the IDL for this function looks like

```
typedef struct  
{   
    LONG time_to_play;
    BSTR ecportid;
} SwitchPlanItem;
HRESULT UpdateSwitchPlan([in] BSTR plan_name, [in] SAFEARRAY(SwitchPlanItem) plan) ;
```

I tried to call it from C# like this:

```
        internal void UpdateSwitch(string plan_name, string ecportid)
    {
        SwitchPlanItem sp1;
        sp1.time_to_play = 33;
        sp1.ecportid = ecportid;

        SwitchPlanItem sp2;
        sp2.time_to_play = 33;
        sp2.ecportid = ecportid;

        SwitchPlanItem[] sps = { sp1, sp2 };

        sdk.UpdateSwitchPlan(plan_name, sps);
    }
```

But it crash.  What is the correct way to pass a SAFEARRAY from C# to COM?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that you're using a `SAFEARRAY` of user defined types (UDT), `SAFEARRAY`s of `VARIANT`, `BSTR` and `IUnknown` work out of the box but for `UDT`s you need to help the marshaller along. See this article in MSDN regarding [Passing Safearray of UDTs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221212.aspx).

Comment: I have the same issue. Is there a way to do this ? The article mentions something from the perspective of native client...

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question is similar to this one:
[COM - [in] parameter as SAFEARRAY(STRUCT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244835/com-in-parameter-as-safearraystruct/7255094)

Basically, the C# client that is using an interface where SAFEARRAY(STRUCT) are passed in, has to define **Embed Interop Types = False** on the imported COM server reference properties.