# COM - [in] parameter as SAFEARRAY(STRUCT)

Tags: com

I am able to call a COM interface method using SAFEARRAY(BSTR) as input. If I define instead a simple (containing only some BSTR-s fields) STRUCT to pass into the COM I get 
"[System.ArgumentException] = {"The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"

The call to my COM server is not made because as it seems the arguments from client does not match the expected arguments on server: E_INVALIDARG

Here is my declaration in IDL:

```
typedef enum UserEntityType
{
    User,
    Group,
    IPAddress
} UserEntityType;

[
    uuid(4786F77E-BA5F-4806-B224-12AA8601A5B1)
]
typedef struct UserEntity
{
    UserEntityType      EntityType;
    BSTR                Value;
} UserEntity;

[id(9)]          HRESULT SetUsers([in] SAFEARRAY(UserEntity) input);
```

The exception is thrown at run-time when a C# 4 client calls SetUsers().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the C# client that was using the exe COM server where

```
SetUsers([in] SAFEARRAY(UserEntity) input)
```

was defined.
In order to fix this (at least for .NET 4.0) one has to change the following property of the imported COM server: **Embed Interop Types = False**

Comment: I still wonder why this setting causes this issue. It indeed solved my problems, but WHY? anybody knows

Comment: @orellabac, when interop types are embedded, .net can't locate the TLB containing the struct.  .Net expects the struct's containing assembly to have the assembly guid match the TLB ID.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75001667/138200

Comment: (I'm only twelve years late :)

Comment: Better late than never. Thanks @Mitch