# TLBX_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED when passing SAFEARRAY of UDT to COM function

Tags: .net-core, com-interop

When I call a COM function passing a `SAFEARRAY` of UDT's (`VT_RECORD`) from .Net 7, I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x80131165
  Message=Typelib export: Type library is not registered. (0x80131165)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.StubHelpers.MngdSafeArrayMarshaler.ConvertSpaceToNative(IntPtr pMarshalState, Object& pManagedHome, IntPtr pNativeHome)
   at IServer.ComputePi(ExampleStruct[] param)
   at ManagedClient.Program.Main(String[] _)
```

The exception does not occur on .Net Framework or from native clients.  It does not occur when the struct is not used in a `SAFEARRAY` or `VARIANT`.  The type library is indeed registered.  Reviewing registry access from the client with `procmon` shows that it appears to be looking for some arbitrary typelib - not the correct one.

Example struct ([full idl](https://gist.github.com/mgaffigan/192cd1ce9e4e74595ebfc4a4bbe48130)) based on [Out-of-process COM Server Demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/out-of-process-com-server/)

```
typedef [uuid(7C88E088-A91F-4AE0-B7BA-B1594CCFCD7E), version(1.0)] struct ExampleStruct {
    long x;
} ExampleStruct;
```

and the parameter:

```
HRESULT ComputePi([in] SAFEARRAY(ExampleStruct) param);
```

Why does this exception occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the .Net SafeArray marshaller cannot load the typelib for the struct.  Confusingly, while the tlb containing the structs has indeed been registered, .Net cannot locate it.  .Net locates the typelib for a struct [by examining the containing assembly](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/26a91ad6ac02393c6c7463500c030ec07803c5e6/src/coreclr/vm/stdinterfaces.cpp#L614).

Unless the assembly has the `GuidAttribute` to specify a typelib ID, it [calculates an id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/t1ztw645(v=vs.100)#library-identifier-libid) from the assembly name, version, and other factors. In .Net Framework, this did not cause issues so long as `tlbexp`/`tlbimp` were used since `[assembly: GuidAttribute()]` was added automatically (though it [would break](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255094/138200) even then if Embed Interop Types was enabled).

There are several ways to fix [the sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/out-of-process-com-server/):

1. Specify `[assembly: Guid("46F3FEB2-121D-4830-AA22-0CDA9EA90DC3")]` in [Contract/IServer.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/main/core/extensions/OutOfProcCOM/Contract/IServer.cs) to make the assemblies match the midl generated typelib
   **Note:** In a non-trivial example where a client may call upon multiple different type-libs, it is necessary to move the COM imports and structs to a separate assembly (1:1 per tlb similar to those generated by `tlbimp`)
2. Use a [tool such as `dscom tlbexport`](https://github.com/dspace-group/dscom) to create the tlb from the assembly (reducing the chance of mismatches both in guids and in binary interface).  An example of such a solution is available at [github in NetCoreOop](https://github.com/mgaffigan/NetCoreOop)